# Should I duplicate test data and assert data?

Tags: unit-testing

The question is probably best asked with a simple example:

```
var myObj = { name: 'John' };
var copiedObj = ObjectCopier.copy(myObj);

copiedObj.name.should.equal('John');     // Hard code 'John' twice
copiedObj.name.should.equal(myObj.name); // Reference the original value
```

Is one method preferred over the other?  Assuming the value passed in is what I expect to be returned, is there any harm in the 2nd assert?  Does it even matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In more complex cases you won't be able to duplicate an object completely - and you wouldn't want to. it would be better written this way:

```
var OBJ_NAME = 'John'
var myObj = { name: OBJ_NAME };
var copiedObj = ObjectCopier.copy(myObj);

copiedObj.name.should.equal(OBJ_NAME);
```

this way you're not duplicating any code/defines, and you can also make tests such as:

```
myObj.name.should.equal(OBJ_NAME);
```

to test for the object copier not changing the original object either (which either of your lines won't test for).